Как убрать автоматический скроллинг сайта на калькулятор
Делаю сайт, возникла проблема: при входе на главную страницу сайт автоматически скроллится ко второму блоку.
Искал решение везде: в CSS, JS, jQuery, но так и не нашел решения. Помогите найти как убрать автоматический скроллинг сайта на калькулятор
https://fintegrator.pro

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

В функции LeasingCalc присутствует вызов
new ScrollTo({
            from: document.querySelector(".leasing-s01__button"),
            to: document.querySelector(".leasing-calc")
        })


Если убрать эту функцию исчезают сами стилусы которые можно двигать. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HhmB8CFXVNv7f6e8YqShIIweyBJqPX87/view?usp=sharing - что делать в таком случае?

Функцию убирать не надо. А в функции нужно убрать вызов скролла на .leasing-calc

Любые попытки изменить эти строчки приводят к тому что пересает работать функционал 2 последних передвигателей, как должна выглядеть эта функция?
